# Giving error when no results are found

Tags: php, mysql

I want the script to give an error when no database entry is found. This script works with the $_GET function. So when for instance. The user typed this in: index.php?id=1054355
and it doesnt find anything. It outputs a message that the entry isnt found.

code i have now:

```
$userid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nieuws WHERE UserID = '$userid'") or die(mysql_error()); 

//fetch the results / convert results into an array

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

$userid = $rows['UserID'];
$titel = $rows['Titel'];
$body = $rows['Body'];
$door = $rows['Door'];
$bron = $rows['Bron']; 

echo 

 "
 <h1><b>Nieuws - $titel</b></h1>
 <p>&nbsp;</P>
 <h4>$body</h4>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <b>Geschreven door: $door</b><p>
 <i>Bronvermelding: $bron</i>
 ";


}

?>
```

I hope somone can come up with a solution,

cheers.

Comment: Please write this script you are talking about, im kinda noobish with MySQL

Comment: did you echo the query and run directly in phpyadmin? does it return any result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use numrows https://www.php.net/mysql_num_rows

You have to notice that mysql will no longer available soon.

Use mysqli instead.

```
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($numRows == 0){
    echo "No record found!";
}
```

Comment: Most simple answer, but very good. This exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$userid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nieuws WHERE UserID = '$userid'") or die(mysql_error()); 

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo 'No rows found';
} else {   

    //fetch the results / convert results into an array

    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

      $userid = $rows['UserID'];
      // etc...
    }
}
```

**Note:** the `mysql_*()` functions are deprecated and will be removed soon. Use `mysqli_*()` or `PDO` for new code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$userid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nieuws WHERE UserID = '$userid'") or die(mysql_error()); 

    if(mysql_fetch_array($query ) == false)
        return 'no data found';

//fetch the results / convert results into an array

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

$userid = $rows['UserID'];
$titel = $rows['Titel'];
$body = $rows['Body'];
$door = $rows['Door'];
$bron = $rows['Bron']; 

echo 

 "
 <h1><b>Nieuws - $titel</b></h1>
 <p>&nbsp;</P>
 <h4>$body</h4>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <b>Geschreven door: $door</b><p>
 <i>Bronvermelding: $bron</i>
 ";


}

?>
```

Another way:

```
if(mysql_fetch_row($query ))
 return "no data found!";
else{
// do your stuff
}
```

in mysqli :

```
if($query->num_rows)
return "no data found!";
    else{
    // do your stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
$row_count = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($row_count === 0)
{
  echo "nothing found" ;
}
else
{
  // your code for the retrieved result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(!$query){ //will return true if query was not successful

    echo 'id could not be found';

   }else{

    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

    $userid = $rows['UserID'];
    $titel = $rows['Titel'];
    $body = $rows['Body'];
    $door = $rows['Door'];
    $bron = $rows['Bron']; 

    echo 

     "
     <h1><b>Nieuws - $titel</b></h1>
     <p>&nbsp;</P>
     <h4>$body</h4>
     <p>&nbsp;</p>
     <p>&nbsp;</p>
     <b>Geschreven door: $door</b><p>
     <i>Bronvermelding: $bron</i>
     ";


    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using mySQLi (which should be used),

```
$write = new mysqli($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password,$db_database); //use your values here
$stmt = $write->prepare("SELECT `UserID`,`Titel`,`Body`,`Door`,`Bron` WHERE `userID` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i',$userId); // i = int, s = string.
$stmt->bind_result($userid,$titel,$body,$door,$bron);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

This is just a basic example, you could do many things to check for results, one such method would be,

```
if(isset($titel)){//code here to do stuff}
```

something that may be worth doing is redirecting the user to a generic page if no results are found,

```
if(!isset($titel){header("location:index.php");} //This checks if titel is set, if not then...
```

as Awlad Linton said you can `mysqli_num_rows()` too which is probably more efficient.